# select & Join tables and combine partially duplicated results

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle18c

[image: erd]I have 5 tables.

I am trying to select and join so that I have one row for each customer returned. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTFNAME || ' ' || CUSTOMER.CUSTLNAME AS "CUSTOMER",
ORDERITEM.ITEMDESC AS "ITEMS PURCHASED", 
RETURNITEM.ITEMDESCS "RETURNS",
STATES.STATENAME
FROM CUSTOMER 
INNER JOIN ORDER ON CUSTOMER.CUSTID = ORDER.CUSTID
INNER JOIN ORDERITEM ON ORDER.OITEMID = ORDERITEM.OITEMID
INNER JOIN RETURN ON CUSTOMER.CUSTID = RETURN.CUSTID
INNER JOIN RETURNITEM ON RETURN.RITEMID = RETURNITEM.RITEMID
INNER JOIN STATES ON CUSTOMER.STATEID = STATES.STATEID;
```

Which works, except...

I have a single customer who has two orders (two items) and two returns (two return items). Rather than seeing:

```
---Customer------ITEMS PURCHASED------------RETURNS

Joe Snuffy       widget 1                   widget 1
joe snuffy       widget 2                   widget 1
joe snuffy       widget 1                   widget 2
joe snuffy       widget 2                   widget 2
```

My end goal is to see:

```
---Customer------ITEMS PURCHASED------------RETURNS

Joe Snuffy       widget 1, widget 2         widget 1, widget 2
```

Is there a way to do that? Preferably one that isn't a super complicated function or something haha...

TIA!

Comment: Do you really have a returned items table and an order items table?  Isn't it just the same list of items?

Comment: Nope. They're separate tables. The front end web app queries the order item info and copies the item info to the returned item table when a return is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too bad your are on 18c instead of 19c, you could use the new `DISTINCT` flag on `LISTAGG`.  As it is, you just need to split it up a bit:

```sql
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTFNAME || ' ' || CUSTOMER.CUSTLNAME AS "CUSTOMER",
o.purchased AS "ITEMS PURCHASED", 
r.returned "RETURNS",
STATES.STATENAME
FROM CUSTOMER c
INNER JOIN (SELECT o.custid, 
                   LISTAGG(oi.itemdesc, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY oi.itemdesc) AS PURCHASED
            FROM ORDER o
            INNER JOIN ORDERITEM oi ON o.OITEMID = oi.OITEMID
            GROUP BY o.custid) o ON c.custid = o.custid
INNER JOIN (SELECT r.custid,
                   LISTAGG(ri.itemdesc, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ri.itemdesc) AS RETURNED
            FROM RETURN r
            INNER JOIN RETURNITEM ri ON r.RITEMID = ri.RITEMID
            GROUP BY r.custid) r ON c.custid = r.custid
INNER JOIN STATES ON CUSTOMER.STATEID = STATES.STATEID;
```

In this code, I just `LISTAGG` the individual lists and then join it all together.

Comment: Genius. I don't know why I didn't think of doing that. You're awesome, thank you so much!